# Approximating a special exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I am interested in the following (modified exponential) function $f$:

$$f(r) = e^{-\sqrt{r^2 + a^2}}$$

where $r$ takes on real values in $[0, \infty]$ and $a$ is a small, but non-zero, real parameter. Since the function $f$ itself is unfortunately too complicated to work with in the applications that interest me, I am looking for useful approximations. In view of the fact that $a$ is small, we may obviously start with this simple approximation:

$$g(r) = e^{-r}$$

My question is, what is the best way to obtain the next term?

Simply expanding $f - g$ for the case $a << r$ yields $h(r) = -0.5 (a^2/r) * e^{-r}$. This is fine, except when $r$ approaches zero. Then the formula for $h$ suggests a $1/r$ divergence which should not be there. It seems to me that the case $0 \le r < a$ must be considered separately. Then the two limiting functions must somehow be merged into a single formula, that works well for all values of $r$ and $a$.

I look forward to your ideas on this matter !

Answer (score 1):

Let $r = t - a$ and expand your function in an asymptotic series in $t$:

$$ \eqalign{f(r) &= e^{a-t} 
\left(1-{\frac {{a}^{2}}{2\;t}}+{\frac {{a}^{3} \left( -4+a \right) 
}{{8\;t}^{2}}}-{\frac {{a}^{4} \left( {a}^{2}-12\,a+18 \right) }{{48\;t
}^{3}}}+\ldots\right)\cr
&= e^{-r} \left(1-{\frac {{a}^{2}}{2\;(r+a)}}+{\frac {{a}^{3} \left( -4+a \right) 
}{{8\;(r+a)}^{2}}}-{\frac {{a}^{4} \left( {a}^{2}-12\,a+18 \right) }{{48\;(r+a)
}^{3}}}+\ldots\right)}$$

With just a few terms, I think you'll find this is a pretty good approximation to $f(r)$ over the whole range $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: This is certainly an elegant and thought-provoking approach. I am currently examining whether the resulting asymptotic series can be cast in a more useful form for my application. Thank you!